# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) data always null

Tags: javascript, php, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to use PHP + GCM + Service Workers to send push notifications to users of my **website** (not app).

```
//service-worker.js
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Received a push message');
    console.log(event.data.text());
});
```

When I go to the Chrome Console >> Application >> Service Workers >> Push the console shows the following:

```
Received a push message
Test push message from DevTools.
```

I am trying to accomplish the same thing using a PHP script:

```
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $ids,
    'data'          => $msg,
);
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
```

The push notification comes through, however, I get the following:

```
Received a push message
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
```

I've tried digging through other properties of `event` with no luck. Most of the help articles I have read are for Android and not for web development. What am I missing?